# python- sort a list by alphabetical order / type / index

Tags: python, python-2.7

hellooo !

I have this list :

`[basketball , football , basketball , tennis , basketball , tennis ]`

as we see , we have 3 basketball , 1 football , 2 tennis
I want to sort it, in alphabetical order and by type of sport, so that there will be an index at the end which is incremented according to the type sport and also adding a suffix "team ". I therefore wish to have this result:

`[basketball-team1 , basketball-team2, bastekball-team3, football-team1, tennis-team1, tennis-team2]`

we suppose we don't know the list values (we don't know it has basketball/football/tennis]

I sorted the list in alphabetical order, I added the suffix "team" but my problem is the index which only increments with the type of sport, I don't know how to do it

help pleaasee ! :)
ps : I have python 2.7

Comment: You could sort the original list, which will do so alphabetically. You could then iterate and perform your changes to append the team counts. To do that, you'll need to have some form of lookup to know what the possible sports are. You'll also need to track how many times you see each one as you go through the sorted list so that you are appending the proper team number for each occurrence.

Comment: thank you , yess I sorted the list in alphabetical order, I added the suffix "team" but my problem is the index which only increments with the type of sport, I don't know how to do it :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to get a dictionary of unique elements and associated counts, and then use that to build the output list that you require.  For example:

```
from collections import Counter

teams = ['basketball', 'football', 'basketball', 'tennis',
         'basketball', 'tennis']

counts = Counter(teams)

out = []
for sport in sorted(counts.keys()):
    count = counts[sport]
    for i in range(1, count + 1):
        out.append("{}-team{}".format(sport, i))

print(out)
```

Gives:

```
['basketball-team1', 'basketball-team2', 'basketball-team3', 'football-team1', 'tennis-team1', 'tennis-team2']
```

You can also use `sorted(counts)` in place of `sorted(counts.keys())` in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good use of [`itertool.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). You can sort the list then let groupby group them. `enumerate()` will give you the index for each item in the groups (it's zero indexed, so you'll need to add one to it).

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['basketball' , 'football' , 'basketball' , 'tennis' , 'basketball' , 'tennis']

[f'{n}-team{index+1}' for k, g in groupby(sorted(l)) for index, n in enumerate(g)]
# ['basketball-team1', 'basketball-team2', 'basketball-team3', 'football-team1', 'tennis-team1', 'tennis-team2']
```

**edit**
The `f` string, doesn't work in python2.x, but it's the same idea. Just concat a string or use whatever formatting you like:

```
['{}-team{}'.format(n, index+1) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l)) for index, n in enumerate(g)]
```

Comment: Thanks @alaniwi didn't notice that. I'll edit (although I'm a little rusty on what's available for string formats in 2.x).

Comment: In 2.7, you have basically all the options from Python 3 aside from f-strings. `str.format` is the easiest drop in replacement and most modern-style option: `'{}-team{}'.format(n, index+1)` would do the trick. You could avoid the manual `+1` by making it `enumerate(g, 1)` (or `enumerate(g, start=1)` if you prefer the explicit named argument).

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger. That's a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use set for unique items and list comprehension to create what you want:

```
data = ['basketball' , 'football' , 'basketball' , 'tennis' , 'basketball' , 'tennis' ] 

output = [ sport + '-team' + str(i) for sport in sorted(set(data)) for i in range(1, data.count(sport) + 1)]
```

Output

```
['basketball-team1', 'basketball-team2', 'basketball-team3', 'football-team1', 'tennis-team1', 'tennis-team2']
```

Comment: Slight tweak: you will want `sorted(set(data))` rather than just `set(data)` (question asks for it sorted).

Comment: OK. Sorted the set.

Answer (score 0):

Uses Counter and sorted in a list comprehension.  Repeats each unique element n times with incrementing counter
repl.it demo: https://repl.it/repls/IllLankyMultithreading

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['basketball', 'football', 'basketball', 'tennis', 'basketball', 'tennis']

print([ "%s-team%s"%(k,i) for k, n in sorted(Counter(a).items()) for i in range(1,n+1) ])
```